# mysql not terminating trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I added a trigger to my mysql database, but when it is used it doesn't terminate. What am I doing wrong?
My query to add the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insertResVals;
DELIMITER $$
create trigger insertResVals
AFTER INSERT
ON lastAccess
        for each row begin
                DECLARE done INT;
                DECLARE res varchar(50);
                DECLARE val double;
                DECLARE sig VARCHAR(140);
                DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT resource, value FROM resourceDefault;
                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
                OPEN cur1;
                SET done = 0;
                read_loop: LOOP
                        FETCH cur1 INTO res, val;
                        IF NOT done THEN
                                LEAVE read_loop;
                        END IF;
                        insert into log
                        select concat(NEW.playerID, ", ", res, ", ", val);

                        if res<>null and val<>null THEN
                                INSERT INTO resourceValue VALUES(NEW.playerID, res, val);
                        ELSE
                                set done = 1;
                        END IF;
                END LOOP;

                CLOSE cur1;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you very much
I tried debugging, but the inserting into the log table did not work (I guess because the transaction is never finished).

Comment: Can you explain in plain words what logic you want to implement with this trigger?

Comment: when a new user is added (by adding to lastAccess), the default values should be retrieved from a second table (resourceDefault) and  be inserted with the additional userid into resourceValue

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in the following line of code:

```sql
...
if res<>null and val<>null THEN
...
```

as this will always be NULL, and evaluates to FALSE.

Change the [12.3.2. Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) `<>` by `IS NOT NULL`:

```
...
IF res IS NOT NULL AND val IS NOT NULL THEN
...
```

**UPDATE**

The following trigger works without problem:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */

/* Trigger structure for table `lastaccess` */

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertResVals`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `insertResVals` AFTER INSERT ON `lastaccess`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT default 0;
    DECLARE res varchar(50);
    DECLARE val double;
    DECLARE sig VARCHAR(140);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT resource, value FROM resourcedefault;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
    OPEN cur1;
    SET done = 0;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO res, val;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        insert into log
        select concat(NEW.playerid, ", ", res, ", ", val);
        if res IS NOT null and val IS NOT null THEN
            INSERT INTO resourcevalue VALUES(NEW.playerid, res, val);
        ELSE
            set done = 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec7d14/1)</kbd>

Comment: i tried that, but when I insert into the "lastAccess" table it never finnishes

Comment: thank you for answering, but `lastaccess` is not the sam as lastAccess so the trigger is accepted, but not used for the table lastAccess.